# Alternative for "particularly interested"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, formality

What are other *formal* ways of saying "I'm particularly interested in..."?

In this case it's for use on cover letters for CVs. The [synonyms for "interested" offered by the thesaurus](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=interested%20synonyms&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=H-rMVK7tD8HnasrygpgL) don't seem appropriate.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what context this is to be used in (conversation, job application, academic article, etc.) and not least what research you have done prior to asking here. Without these details, the question is not practically answerable and is off-topic.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for input, I've updated question to hopefully suit the requirements.

Comment: I am not [riveted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rivet) by this question. And certainly not [fascinated](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fascinated) or [focused](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/focused?s=t).

Comment: While intending no denigration of the answer you have selected (Mr. Jacquet consistently provides cogent answers & commentary) by officially selecting the first (and only) answer posted, you have 1) made a "choice" without benefit of comparison; and 2) disincentivized any further community involvement. Whereas, by postponing official selection you avail yourself of the community and the opportunity to make a choice based upon comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is for a CV, I am going to assume that your interests here are *professional* (or academic) interests, rather than what you like to do in your spare time.

Your initial version, “I am particularly interested in”, works just fine. If you’re looking specifically for something that sounds more formal and ‘business-like’, a few suggestions could be:

> My primary interests are [in the field(s) of] …
>   My main focus is on …
>   Pivotal/essential/preeminent/major foci of my work include …

The last of these is significantly more formal than the others, bordering on being archaic. The first two are more natural and neutral in register.

The first talks mostly about what you find interesting topics, while the second and especially the third describe specific things that you have already specialised in and done work on.

Comment: Focus, as above; also "concentration".  I hear that the kids these days use "obsessed with" on their their twitter CVs.